# Calculating running total for each Year

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to calculate running total ,year wise. If user selects date as "Dec 2023" it should show running total from Jan 2023- Dec 2023.

Few examples are given below

| User Selection (in slicer dropdown) | Running Total |
| --- | --- |
| Jan '2023 | To show data for Jan 2023 |
| June '2023 | Sum from Jan 2023 to June 2023 |
| October 2023 | Sum from Jan 2023 to October 2023 |
| December 2023 | Sum from Jan 2023 to December 2023 |
| Jan 2024 | Sum of Jan 2024 only *(no sum of 2023 year)* |
| Mar 2024 | Sum of Jan + Feb + Mar for 2024 year |

It is not YTD calculation but it is calendar year calculation. What logic I need to write-in? Please note that Month filter is in form of  "December 2023" i.e. Month Year

I have tried YTD but that is not the requirement is

Comment: do you have a date table for this report? What other date columns are available? Year, MonthYearInt?YearOffset?

Comment: some data to replicate your requets please ?